# How to access MEDIA_ROOT files within the view

Tags: django, django-views

How to i get the file (where all the uploaded images are held when a user uploads an image), contained in the MEDIA_ROOT. I want to delete this file when the user deletes their account and all the uploaded images within it.

```
def function(request):
    user_file = user_file_object
    if request.method == 'POST':
    # deletes the user file
       user_file.delete()
       user.delete()
```

Comment: You need to explain your question a bit more clearly. `request.FILES` contains the files being sent in the request itself. What does that have to do with MEDIA_ROOT? What *exactly* are you trying to do?

Comment: sorry, how do i get files contained in the "media_cdn" in the view function

Comment: Whata is media_cdn? And why do you need to access it in the view?

Comment: The media_cdn folder is where all the users images are uploaded to, i want to delete the users folder that contains there uploaded images when they delete there account.

Answer (score 2):

I am sure you have defined `MEDIA_URL` in your `settings.py` file. Something like this.

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

To access the `MEDIA_URL` in your view use below code.

```
from django.conf import settings

def my_view(request):
    media_url = settings.MEDIA_URL
    path_to_user_folder = media_url + "/user_name/"
    # delete the folder.
```

Comment: I needed to save the generated file, so the following line helped me: `media_url = settings.MEDIA_ROOT`